# Concatenate to a field without using a separate field?

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge, field-codes

How can I concatenate a space to a mail merge field in Word?

Ideally:

- The space should be part of the field
- The space should be omitted if the field is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for ['\f' switch](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-MergeField-field-7a6d24a1-68a6-4b05-8359-1dc087daf4e6):

> \f
>
> Specifies the text to be inserted following the MergeField field if the field is not blank.

and the example:

> { MERGEFIELD CoutesyTitle \f " " }{ MERGEFIELD FirstName \f " " }{
>   MERGEFIELD LastName }
>
> Results in the following:
>
> - If all fields are present: Ms. Mindy Martin
> - If FirstName is missing from the data source: Ms. Martin